# Can you use a function's return type as a type elsewhere?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a callback that takes the result of another function as input. Is there a way to directly reference that function's return type? Currently I have the return type defined as a type alias that I can use in both places but that doesn't seem ideal. Does something like C++'s [std::result_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) exist in python?

#### Current Code

```py
from typing import Tuple

func_return = Tuple[int, int]
def func() -> func_return:
    return 1, 1

def call_back(arg: func_return) -> int:
    a, b = arg
    return a + b
```

#### Ideal Code

```py
from typing import Tuple

def func() -> Tuple[int, int]:
    return 1, 1

def call_back(arg: return_type(func)) -> int:
    a, b = arg
    return a + b
```

Comment: *"that doesn't seem ideal"* Why? both cases follow DRY and require a single change (if the **type** changes). If anything, in the "ideal" code there is a higher coupling between the 2 functions. Changing `func`'s name will require a change everywhere `return_type(func)` is used.

Comment: It's not ideal, because you are focusing on the wrong thing. It's the *type* you care about, not the function that produces a value of that type.

Comment: counterpoint: TypeScript provides a few "utility types" of this kind (including `ReturnType`) that are useful sometimes https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype examples of usage https://medium.com/@curtistatewilkinson/typescript-2-8-and-a-simple-example-of-returntype-ab454da83934 I love Python but I can't help feeling that TS does a better job applying static typing to a similarly messy dynamic language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because `call_back` only knows/cares about the *value*, not which function produces the value. `call_back` takes a value, and it's the caller's responsibility to provide a value of the correct type, whether or not they use a function to produce that value.

Focus on the *type*, not the functions that produce or accept values of that type.

```
IntPair = Tuple[int, int]

def func() -> IntPair:
    return 1, 1

def call_back(arg: IntPair) -> int:
    a, b = arg
    return a + b
```

(Same as your current code, but with a name that focuses on what the type is, not where it *might* come from:

```
# All legal, all equivalent
call_back(func())
call_back((1, 1))
call_back((1,) + (1,))
```

)

Comment: That's a great point. The focus should be on what the type represents. I'll come up with a better name for my type and use that instead of caring about what happens to produce that type.